# Representation of vector spaces as direct product

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose $V$ is an $(n+m)/2$-dimensional linear subspace of $GF(2)^n\times GF(2^m)$. Is it possible, without loss of generality, to assume that $V$ is of the form $V=U\times W$, where $U,W$ are linear subspaces such that $\dim(U)+\dim(W)=(n+m)/2$?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not the case, since, for example in the case $n=m=1$, $V$ might be
$$V=\mathrm{span}\{(1,1)^T \},$$
i.e. a diagonal line.

Comment: What about n,m>2 and bot dimensions are even?